# Validar un XML con un XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-schema

Estoy intentando crear un **XSD** para validar una serie de documentos generados en formato **XML**.

He intentado lo siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="proceso_cajero">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="evento">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="ID_INSTANCIA" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="ACTIVIDAD" type="xs:string" />          
            </xs:sequence>
              <xs:any minOccurs="1"/>

          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Lo que necesito e intento hacer en ese fragmento del código es validar que el fichero XML tenga 2 elementos dentro del elemento `"evento"` en ese orden `"ID_INSTANCIA"` - `"ACTIVIDAD"` y luego varios elementos pero no obligatorios. **Si es obligatorio que venga al menos un elemento luego de la secuencia**.

El fichero XML objetivo puede tener esta estructura:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<proceso_cajero>
  <evento>
    <ID_INSTANCIA>XXXXX</ID_INSTANCIA>
    <ACTIVIDAD>XXXXXXXXX</ACTIVIDAD>

    <MONEDA>XXX</MONEDA>
    <MONTO>XXX</MONTO>

  </evento>
</proceso_cajero>
```

Al intentar realizar la validacion me muestra un error en la línea donde declaro el elemento `<xs:any>`:

> "Unable to parse schema file, the content is not valid expected is (annotation,simplecontent,complexcontent, ... )"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los elementos obligatorios deben tener el atributo `minOccurs="1"` y luego de cerrado un `xs:sequence` no puedes poner más elementos, debes iniciar otro `xs:sequence` u otra estructura.

En tu caso, el elemento `any` hace parte de la secuencia como último elemento y el esquema quedaría así:

```
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="evento">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="ID_INSTANCIA" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
          <xs:element name="ACTIVIDAD" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
          <xs:any minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="skip"/>
        </xs:sequence>

      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: He intentado lo que me dices, me retorna el siguiente error -->  ERROR: Element 'XXX': No matching global element declaration available, but demanded by the strict wildcard. Donde 'XXX' es el elemento debajo de "ACTIVIDAD"  en el fichero XML.

Comment: Me faltó incluir el atributo maxOccurs="unbounded" para que puedaas tener varios elementos opcionales. Según el validador de XML que uses, puede que requieras también el atributo processContents="skip"